# matlab plots as movie with legend

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, movie

i have a question regarding legend for movies.
This is my code:

```
fig = figure();
for i = 1: 70000
plot(signal1)
hold on;
plot([i,i],[-5,5])
plot(signal2,'r')
hold off;
title('\fontsize{14} my data');
legend('signal1','signal2');
axis tight;
f(i) = getframe(fig); 
end
```

The legend shows the same colors for the first two things I plot. if I plot more it works for the other plots. Is there a trick I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings defined in the `legend` command are assigned in order of the plots being generated. This means that your first string `'signal1'` is assigned to the plot for `signal1` and the second string `'signal2'` is assigned to the vertical line.

You have two possibilities to fix this problem.

1. Execute `plot` for the vertical line after the plot for the two signals.
2. Use handles to the plots to assign the legends directly.

Here is an example of **changing the order**:

```
plot(signal1)
hold on;
plot(signal2,'r')
plot([i,i],[-5,5],'k')
hold off;
legend('signal1','signal2');
```

Here is an example that **uses handles** (`sp1` and `sp2`):

```
sp1 = plot(signal1)
hold on;
plot([i,i],[-5,5],'k')
sp2 = plot(signal2,'r')
hold off;
title('\fontsize{14} my data');
legend([sp1,sp2],'signal1','signal2');
```

Comment: thank you. Just one line somewhere else and everything works :)

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you want to be independent of the position, use the second approach. This is especially recommended if there are more curves on a plot then legend entries.